# How to get id value from div and autoclick using jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to get id value and auto click on that url

here's the code

```
<div id="testinglink">
<div class="a1">
<a href="http://facebook.com" id="d1">click here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by auto click on that url?

Comment: @Madiri Salman Aashish: You comments below indicate that you do not have jQuery included properly, or your script code is placed incorrectly. Please show your entire page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click triggering does not work for anchors in jQuery, but you can call the native DOM element click:

```
  $('#d1')[0].click();
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3r25e1c1/

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("d1").click();
```

Comment: He said using jquery.

Comment: `.click()` on a jQuery element only generates a jQuery event and does not trigger the anchor click. See my answer for simple way around this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.a1 a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get ID of the Element
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    // do whatever you want
    // document.location.href = link;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/2k8b6dpg/)**

Comment: If you use `document.location.href = link;` then it will redirect the url

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you do it:

```
$('#d1').trigger('click')
```

The anchor will not be clicked as if it is physically clicked by a user. But the functionality of click will still be achieved. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/j2rhocpw/) is fiddle. After you trigger the click you can redirect the page to facebook as below. 
HTML:

```
<div id="testinglink">
<div class="a1">
<a href="http://facebook.com" id="d1">click here</a>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#d1').on('click',function(e){
     window.location = e.currentTarget.href;
})

$('#d1').trigger('click')
```

Comment: Click triggering does not work for links in jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/3r25e1c1/1/

Comment: As you have just confirmed yourself, `trigger('click`)` only generates a jQuery event. *It does not trigger an actual click*.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Well there is no way to physically trigger a click on anchor tags.. so I have tried to post one of the simplest ways to achieve it through jquery.
OP: You seem to have misconfigured jquery. Can you reproduce your problem on a jsfiddle?